# How can other users view a user's profile details in octobercms?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

Displaying a user's information to the user is pretty much straight forward using their id or name in the url as parameter and displaying specific details using `{{ user.name }}`, `{{ user.phone }}`  etc.  But how can i display a specific user info to other users. When i click on www.example.com/profile/joe, it takes me to joe's profile. Trying it logged out or from a different account throws up an error.

This what i have done so far. my profile url has

```
 url = "/:id"
```

and my php block

```
 [session]
 ==
 <?php function onStart(){
$profile = $this->param('id');  
} 
?> 
==
```

this links up to the profile page

```
<a href="{{ 'profile'|page ({ id: user.name }) }}"><button style="font-family: arial" class="btn btn-sm btn-light rounded--lg-pill shadow rounded border col-6">View Profile</button></a>
```

using `{{ user.name }}`, `{{ user.phone }}` etc shows all the logged in user's info. I am just at lost here how to make the profile of a user available to other users.

**Edit**:
Currently working if i use `$userProfile = Auth::findUserById($profile)`

connected to `<a href = ''{{ id: users.id }}''>View Profile></a>`

It still works if I change it to
`$userProfile = Auth::findUserByLogin($profile)` 
 connected to
  `<a href = ''{{ id: users.username }}''>View Profile></a>` 
or 
`<a href = ''{{ id: users.email }}''>View Profile></a>`

but i would have loved it to work using a different field

`<a href = ''{{ id: user.company_name }}''>View Profile></a>` instead of id or login details

Comment: You're not doing the effort to provide more information about what you have tried so far using code examples which makes it hard to provide an accurate answer. As for the question above, you need to retrieve the route URI param (joe), search the DB for that specific alias and get the data you need.

Comment: This what i have done so far. my profile url has ````url = "/:id"```` and my php block ````[session]

==
<?php
function onStart(){$profile  =  $this->param('id'); 


}
?>
==```` this links up to the profile page ````<a href="{{ 'profile'|page ({ id: user.name }) }}"><button style="font-family: arial" class="btn btn-sm btn-light rounded--lg-pill shadow rounded border col-6">View Profile</button></a>````  using {{ user.name }}, {{ user.phone }} etc shows all the logged in user's info. I am just at lost here how to make the profile of a user available to other users.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we are generating link : `www.example.com/profile/joe`

so id will be `joe` now we need to find that user's record and use it

> to find it in code

```
[session]
==
<?php function onStart(){
     $profile = $this->param('id');  
     $this['userProfile'] = Auth::findUserByLogin($profile);
     // you can use other field if you need 
     // $this['userProfile'] = \RainLab\User\Models\User::where('username', $profile)->first();
} 
?> 
==
```

> use it in template

```
{{ userProfile.name }}, {{ userProfile.phone }}
```

if any doubts please add comment.

Comment: It works now. by changing the id parameter to ```{{ id: user.id }}``` but would have loved to make it work with some other parameter too like ```{{ id:user.company_name }}```

Comment: can you share full example code of it how you want to use it, may be we can help you

Comment: updated answer, added comment code section it may help you